# Corrupt empty row found in unfiltered partition

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster consisting of 15 nodes.
The Cassandra version is 3.7.0

I am constantly getting an error message in the log messages of almost all nodes.

The recurring error message is exactly as follows:

```
ERROR [BatchlogTasks:1] 2023-03-22 10:13:20,281 CassandraDaemon.java:217 - Exception in thread Thread[BatchlogTasks:1,5,main]
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Corrupt empty row found in unfiltered partition
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer$1.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:224) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer$1.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:212) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate$PartitionUpdateSerializer.deserialize30(PartitionUpdate.java:681) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate$PartitionUpdateSerializer.deserialize(PartitionUpdate.java:656) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation$MutationSerializer.deserialize(Mutation.java:341) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation$MutationSerializer.deserialize(Mutation.java:350) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager$ReplayingBatch.addMutations(BatchlogManager.java:353) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager$ReplayingBatch.<init>(BatchlogManager.java:304) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager.processBatchlogEntries(BatchlogManager.java:237) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.batchlog.BatchlogManager.replayFailedBatches(BatchlogManager.java:207) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:118) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Corrupt empty row found in unfiltered partition
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.deserialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:388) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer$1.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:219) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

I use the default configuration settings in cassandra.yaml.

I think the reason for this error is because of a table. Before this error, I was getting CorruptSSTableException error and I solved it with nodetool scrub.

Here's what I've tried to resolve this error:

- Restarting the nodes
- Running Nodetool scrub
- Running a repair with the Reaper tool

Comment: Help us to help you by following this guide on how to ask a question. https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it's more appropriate now.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace indicates that the exception is thrown while replaying failed batches.

Looking at [the code for `UnfilteredSerializer.deserialize()`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.7/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.java#L359-L391), Cassandra runs into a problem deserialising a range tombstone and running into an empty row unexpectedly. In my experience, this is due to data corruption.

You mentioned that you see `CorruptSSTableException` errors. You need to figure out if there are problems with the data disk that is leading to the corruption because you will keep running into problems until you can address the root cause.

For a bit of background, [logged] batch mutations are stored in the `system.batchlog` table on two random nodes so if the data is corrupted on one node, Cassandra should still be able to replay it from the batch log on another node.

Note that by design, the `system` keyspace is configured with `LocalStrategy` so it is not replicated to other nodes which means that repairing the `batchlog` table will not help here.

As a side note, there are known issues with range tombstones and running a very old version of Cassandra is not ideal. This particular issue you are running into isn't very common and although I'm not saying upgrading to the latest version of the 3.11 line will fix it, it doesn't help that C* 3.7 is 6 years old (released in June 2016) and there are countless amount of fixes for known issues released since. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, really appreciate it. So what can I do to solve the data corruption (empty row)? If I do a major compaction, will it help? Or, is there any way I can detect SSTables with empty rows, so I can delete those files and run a repair? (since RF=3)

Comment: As I explained above, the `system` keyspace is not replicated so you can't repair the `batchlog` table. You have to rely on the "other node" to be able to replay the batched mutations. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick, I've checked system.batchlog table and there is no single row in the table. I think the reason is different than the batchlog table. I still assume that the reason is corrupted data from one of my tables. I wonder how to solve corrupted empty row on a table that we created in our keyspace.

Comment: It's not just a single row -- it can't read the SSTable(s) for whatever reason. I think you need to read my answer in full to understand what is going on. Cheers!